# When were quarks discovered?

Tags: history, quarks

I know this sounds stupid. Especially to those of you who are actual physicists. I am a 7th grade above-level student who knows a little bit more that the basics of physics. I have recently discovered quarks in searching about atoms and the makeup of Nitrogen-14. I know that we have known about quarks for a while now, but exactly HOW long have we known about them? Who discovered them, and when?

Comment: did you try to search for _quark history_ on wikipedia or google ? or just _quark_

Comment: If it's hard to deal with Wikipedia, click here and read a few paragraphs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#History

Comment: Aw, man. Down votes! Yes, he could have looked it up. Sure tell him so. But give a guy a break.

Answer (score 1):

> **who discovered [quarks]**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark#History):

> The quark model was independently proposed by physicists Murray Gell-Mann and George Zweig ...

---

> **and when**

The Wikipedia article continues:

> ... in 1964.
>
> The proposal came shortly after Gell-Mann's 1961 formulation of a particle classification system known as the Eightfold Way—or, in more technical terms, SU(3) flavor symmetry. Physicist Yuval Ne'eman had independently developed a scheme similar to the Eightfold Way in the same year.